# React component is rendering but not updating when state is updating

Tags: reactjs

React component is showing data when state is null but, when its getting data then its not updating the content of the view.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        post: null
    }

    this.getTotalDownloadSize = this.getTotalDownloadSize.bind(this); 

}

componentWillMount(){
    const {match} = this.props;
    const postId = _.get(match, 'params.id');
    getDownloadInfo(postId).then((response) => {
        this.setState({
            post: _.get(response, 'data')
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("an error while fetching data", err);
    })
}
```

inside my render i am getting null value for render(){

```
render(){
    const {post} = this.state;
    console.log{post};
    const files = _.get(post, 'files', []);
)
```

initially its showing the null value but after it has value but its not updating the content of the view.
can anyone help me with this.
thanks in advance.

Comment: from the example it looks quiet certain that your `getDownloadInfo` method is asynchronous in nature and returns a promise. `componentWillMount()` function might end up being called multiple times before the initial `render()` is called so might result in triggering multiple side-effects. Due to this fact it is not recommended to use this function for any side-effect causing operations(AJAX calls). try with `componenetDidMount()`

Comment: First time you will get `null` because your state is defaulted to `null`. You have to check if your state is not `null` then render, otherwise render something like `loading`

Comment: Could you please `console.log` the `response`?

Comment: Are you sure your method `getDownloadInfo` is working?

Comment: @TheReason i tried using componentDidMount() but its giving the error.

Comment: @TimBJames yes its working. and i can successfully log it into console

Comment: @SergeyVorobey {…}
`result: {…}
_id: "5a93a9a1daec82c97c4ad8af"
created: "2018-02-26T06:30:57.054Z"
files: Array [ {…}, {…} ]
from: "ankitbaid11326@outlook.com"
message: "hey, whats going on?"
to: "ankitbaid11326@gmail.com"
__proto__: Object { … }
__proto__: Object { … }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

componentDidMount is place where you can place request logic.

```
componentDidMount() {
     const {match} = this.props;
        const postId = _.get(match, 'params.id');
        getDownloadInfo(postId).then((response) => {
            this.setState((state) => ({ post: _.get(response, 'data')}));
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("an error while fetching data", err);
        })
    }
```

Comment: which issue you are facing now. ?

Comment: same issue. its not rendering the new data.

Comment: try this in your response this.setState((state) => ({ post: _.get(response, 'data')}));

Answer (score 0):

If your data came from an asynchronous request you should use `componentDidMount`

> Invoked once, only on the client (not on the server), immediately
>   after the initial rendering occurs. At this point in the lifecycle,
>   you can access any refs to your children (e.g., to access the
>   underlying DOM representation). The componentDidMount() method of
>   child components is invoked before that of parent components.
>
> If you want to integrate with other JavaScript frameworks, set timers
>   using setTimeout or setInterval, or send AJAX requests, perform those
>   operations in this method.